# What's the grade of D-glucose that can be used in glucose assimilation test in bacteriology?

Tags: biochemistry, microbiology, bacteriology, glucose

### Background information

Carbon assimilation test is based on the ability of a bacterial species to utilize an organic compound (e.g. D-glucose) as a sole carbon source.
This means that for carbon assimilation tests, any compound that is a potential source of carbon is considered a contaminant (e.g. Maltose for glucose assimilation test).

### Question

What D-glucose grade can be used in glucose assimilation test in bacteriology, specifically, *Acinetobacter* species bacteria?

For example, this product (DEXTROSE MONOHYDRATE Extra Pure)
https://www.alphachemika.co/chemical/2120/DEXTROSE_MONOHYDRATE_Extra_Pure.html
says that it has 0.01% maltose, is this significant?